# regex_search returns true, but regex_match returns empty match set

Tags: c++, regex, std

This is weird, I have the following std::regex (rx)

```
\{\{alternate form of\s*\|(?:\d=)?(.*?)([\|#][^\|}]*)*\}\}
```

which regex_search returns true for when given this string (str)

```
{{alternate form of|abate|nodot=1}} {{qualifier|abbot}}.
```

but when I call regex_match(str, m, rx), the match set m is empty. Using JavaScript mode in RegexBuddy (which seems to be the closest in behaviour I can find to VS2012's regex support) the matches are correctly found. Anyone got any ideas? The regex looks overspecified because some other strings need extra pieces matched...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regex_search` matches any part of the target string. `regex_match` matches the entire string. The regular expression matches the first part of the target string, "{{alternate form of|abate|nodot=1}}". That's what `regex_search` finds. That's not the entire string, which is why `regex_match` doesn't find a match.